# Why single_child() does not work in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment where I must create a family tree in prolog. While all my functions work the single_child does not, returning always false. Inside each function we are only allowed to use child_of(CHILD, PARENT) and female(PERSON). This is what I have wrote (I have omitted the other functions as well as people assignments).

```
:- discontiguous
    child_of/2,
    female/1,
    single_child/1.

single_child(CHILD) :- 
   child_of(CHILD, PARENT), 
   SIBLING \= CHILD, 
   \+ child_of(SIBLING, PARENT).
```

Also, moving the `SIBLING \= CHILD` after `\+ child_of(SIBLING, PARENT)` gives an 'Singleton variable' error. Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: To express "there is no other child of `Parent`", i.e., "there is no child of `Parent` different from `Child`", you would write:

```
single_child(Child) :-
    child_of(Child, Parent),
    \+ ( child_of(Sibling, Parent), Sibling \= Child ).
```

(Not tested because you didn't give us any test cases.)

A key point is that the two goals `child_of(Sibling, Parent), Sibling \= Child` *together* express the condition "there is another child of `Parent`", so you have to negate them *together* to get the right meaning. My preferred way would be to extract this to a separate predicate meaning "`Person` has sibling `Sibling`":

```
person_sibling(Person, Sibling) :-
    child_of(Person, Parent),
    child_of(Sibling, Parent),
    Person \= Sibling.
```

And then write `single_child` as:

```
single_child(Child) :-
    child_of(Child, _Parent),            % Child is somebody's child
    \+ person_sibling(Child, _Sibling).  % Child has no siblings
```

Another key point is that you should only use `\=` when both sides are bound to non-variable terms. In your code `Sibling` is not bound to anything at the point you reach the `\=` goal. That is why my code first calls `child_of(Sibling, Parent)` to give `Sibling` a concrete value before then comparing that concrete value to `Child`. Modern Prologs usually have a `dif` predicate that does not have this restriction: You can write `dif(Child, Sibling), child_of(Sibling, Parent)` and it will do the right thing even if some operands are unbound variables at that point. If your Prolog has `dif`, you should use it instead of `\=`. You can and usually *should* use `dif` before all of its operands become bound.

Final note: You shouldn't just blindly make all your predicates `discontiguous`. It may be useful for facts like `child_of` or `female` if you want to mix up the order of those facts. But as a beginner you should never encounter a situation where it makes sense for a *rule* like `single_child` to be marked discontiguous. In fact, the annotation does not make any sense for a predicate that consists of a single clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `discontiguous` is not so interesting, but this is:

```
single_child(CHILD) :- 
   child_of(CHILD, PARENT), 
   SIBLING \= CHILD,               <----- what is SIBLING at this point?
   \+ child_of(SIBLING, PARENT).
```

You never collect a valid SIBLING from the database.

In fact, the only thing we know about SIBLING is that it is a term that does not unify with CHILD.

That could be anything - but Prolog needs to pick from a finite domain.

Tell it where to find SIBLING.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to prolog, so could you explain how to tell prolog where to find SIBLING? I would move SIBLING \= CHILD after \+ child_of(SIBLING, PARENT) as stated in my question so prolog would 'know' where to look but it would give me a Singleton variable error.

Comment: @GeorgeTsak You have to grab SIBLING from the Prolog database first, i.e. insert the goal `child_of(SIBLING,PARENT)` after `child_of(CHILD, PARENT)`. Then `CHILD` and `SIBLING` exist and have the same PARENT, but you also have to enforce that `CHILD \== SIBLING` (using `\==` rather than `\=`). I don't understand the `\+ child_of(SIBLING, PARENT).` though, what is it supposed to do?